# How to write a method that returns an object and an integer?

Tags: java, methods

Working on a project where I making an AI that can successfully play pac-man. I have a method that gets a specific ghost and the distance from pac-man but I can only return the specific ghost object or the distance from it to pac-man, when I need both values to proceed. My current solution basically has two methods that are exactly the same but with different names and different returns, one an object and one an int.

Ex.

```
public Ghost closestDefender1()
{
code

return Ghost;
}

public int closestDefender2()
{
code

return int;
}
```

Again the code in both methods is exactly the same.

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to make a data class of your own, since Java doesn't have tuples.

Answer (score 1):

In pure OOP you can't really set a value because you initialise some values and then call a method to calculate something with those values. So think about letting the Ghost object be able to calculate the value of the integer, if you have to keep to code that modifies the integer in the closestDefender function then consider setting the integer into the Ghost object and then only return that so you don't need to have two functions with exactly the same code but returning different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a single method to return two types of objects. 
But instead of having redundant code in two places, Create a method to do the processing.

```
public Ghost closestDefender1()
{
    somefunction();
    return Ghost;
}

public int closestDefender2()
{
    somefunction();
    return int;
}
```

Here somefunction() will do the necessary processing and let the methods to decide the return type.

Comment: You can have a single method return several objects of different types, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.  Just declare a special class to return both the Object and the int.  By using generics you can support any type of object that the method is capable of processing.

Either value will be available for appropriate access.

```
    public <T> MyObject<T> method() {
           // do something
          T ob = null;  // or some object value
          int x = 10;
          return new MyObject<>(ob, x);
    }

    class MyObject<T> {
         public T object;
         public int v;
         public MyObject(T o, int v) {
             this.v = v;
             this.object = o;
         }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this example, pretty much exactly what I am trying to do. My current assignment restricts me from creating any new classes but I will keep this in mind for any future projects.

Comment: OK.  As long as this helps at some point that is all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Ghost object holds some coordinates for its position, and I assume you use these coordinates to calculate the distance between Pac-Man and the Ghost...

So maybe make a function for getting the closest ghost. Then make a function for calculating the distance from Pac-Man to any arbitrary Ghost.

Something like this :

```java
public Ghost getClosestGhost() {
    // Find Closest Ghost...
    return closestGhost;
}

public int getDistanceFromGhost(Ghost g) {
    // Calculate Distance from g using its coordinates.
    return distance;
}
```

To use this code, we simply need to run the following...

```java
Ghost closest = getClosestGhost();
int distanceFromClosest = getDistanceFromGhost(closest);
```

With this solution, no code should be repeated. You could even use `getDistanceFromGhost` in your `getClosestGhost` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own Class that extends the `Number` class, and implements an interface.

```java
public class NumericObject extends java.lang.Number implements AnInterface {

}
```

You can now use it either as a `Number` or as a `AnInterface`

```java
public NumericObject closestDefender() {

}

// all are fine
Number closestDefender = closestDefender();
AnInterface closestDefender = closestDefender();
NumericObject closestDefender = closestDefender();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot have your data class to return more than one value from a method, you can return an array or a list or a map, containing Objects that you then cast to what you know they are.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Integer, Object> myResult = myMethod();

        Integer myInteger = (Integer) myResult.get(1);

        System.out.println("1st value: " + myInteger);

        Date myDate = (Date) myResult.get(2);

        System.out.println("2nd value: " + myDate);

        String myString = (String) myResult.get(3);

        System.out.println("3rd value: " + myString);

        List<Object> myResultB = myMethodB();

        myInteger = (Integer) myResultB.get(0);

        System.out.println("1st value: " + myInteger);

        myDate = (Date) myResultB.get(1);

        System.out.println("2nd value: " + myDate);

        myString = (String) myResultB.get(2);

        System.out.println("3rd value: " + myString);

        Object[] myResultC = myMethodC();

        myInteger = (Integer) myResultC[0];

        System.out.println("1st value: " + myInteger);

        myDate = (Date) myResultC[1];

        System.out.println("2nd value: " + myDate);

        myString = (String) myResultC[2];

        System.out.println("3rd value: " + myString);
    }

    static Map<Integer, Object> myMethod() {

        Map<Integer, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

        result.put(1, Integer.valueOf(100));

        result.put(2, new Date());

        result.put(3, "Test");

        return result;
    }

    static List<Object> myMethodB() {

        List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

        result.add(Integer.valueOf(100));

        result.add(new Date());

        result.add("Test");

        return result;
    }

    static Object[] myMethodC() {

        Object[] result = new Object[3];

        result[0] = Integer.valueOf(100);

        result[1] = new Date();

        result[2] = "Test";

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: your first method is very helpful. Is there any way i can get the specific values of 1,2,3 as well when i return? lets say i made it a map, how would i be able to assign the values of 1,2,3 to another variable? I can assign the return results (100,date,"test") to other variables. but not 1,2,3.

Comment: You need to cast, if I understood your question. I updated the answer. Anyway the map solution is probably not the most efficient, if you don't need a map I would go with the array or List.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by making my method "public static Object[]", i made my method return an object array and initialized [0] to be the ghost object, and [1] to be an integer